# Failed to load module 'nvidia' after upgrading to Stretch

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia

I have recently upgraded my laptop from Debian Jessie to Stretch.

X server stopped working. The laptop's Nv card is Gforce GT325M.
The original driver I use with Jessie is installed via Nvidia's installer instead of Debian apt.

I tried to reinstall with the same installer. It didn't work.
I also tried Debian packaged drivers. uninstalling Nvidia driver, installing `nvida-legacy-340xx-driver` pacakge. together with `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-3`

None of them worked for me, all resulting the same error in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` 'Failed to load module 'nvidia' (module does not exist, 0)'

I can see `nvidia` module loaded in `lsmod` output.

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia 9506816 0
drm     253952 2 nvidia
```

greping for the kernel modules gives this:

```
find /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae/|grep nvidia
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/nvidia
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/forcedeth.ko
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae/updates/dkms/nvidia-legacy-340xx.ko
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae/updates/dkms/nvidia-legacy-340xx-uvm.ko
```

after installing the Debain packaged driver. I noticed that the nvidia alternative for GLX has disappeared.

```
update-alternative --query glx
name: glx
link: /usr/lib/glx
.....
status: auto
best: /usr/lib/mesa-diverted
...
alternative: /usr/lib/mesa-diverted
```

there is no nvidia related entry.
I remember when I use nvidia installer, the nvidia alternative was there and was chosen. but that didn't make any change to the `startx` failure and the error message in xorg log.

The xorg.conf file is ok. the original one left in my user directory when Jessie was still kicking and the nvidia-xconfig generated in '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' looks the same like below:

```
serverlayout "layout0"
    screen "screen0"
        monitor "monitor0"
            ventorname "unknown"
            modelname  "unknown"
            vertrefresh 43.0-72.0
            option "dpms"
        device "device0"
            driver "nvidia"
            vendorname "nvidia corperotion"
        default colordepth 24
    ...
```

I have never troubleshoot X related issue before. Thanks in advance.