# Xorg crashes when using nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia

Recently, I had installed a new-old graphic card, Nvidia GeForce 9600GT. My PC is running Debian 9:

```
root@bilkis:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Release:    9.1
Codename:   stretch

root@bilkis:~# uname -a
Linux bilkis 4.9.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) i686 GNU/Linux
```

Then, I had installed proprietary nvidia driver, nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver, from stable repo.
Problem is, that when I startx as a user, it shows my desktop for a second, then fails, all I see is black screen, monitor led is blinking (as if there's no signal). X is not responding on Ctrl-Alt-Backspace, power button is also  not working, leds on keyboard is also off, so I have to hold it to shutdown.
But when I startx as a root, it starts fine, there's no problem, but if I launch some game, e.g. Urban Terror, it plays for 5 or 10 minutes, then fails all the same.

There's xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 340.101  (buildd@debian)  Fri Jan 13 04:25:47 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: builtin, VertRefresh source: builtin
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-1"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 80.30
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 96.0

    # 1280x1024 74.90 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 80.30 kHz; pclk: 138.75 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_75.00"  138.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1027 1034 1072 -hsync +vsync
    Option "DPMS"
    Option "UseEDID" "False"
    Option "ModeValidation" "NoEdidModes"    
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9600 GT"
    Option     "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "yes"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option "IgnoreEDID" "true"
   # Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
   Option "UseEDID" "False"
   Option "SLI" "Off"
   SubSection     "Display"
          Depth       24
          Modes    "1280x1024_75.00"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Edid was disabled due to vga-to-dvi connector related issues.

There's Xorg.0.log when run as a user:

```
[   155.427] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[   155.427] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   155.427] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 i686 Debian
[   155.427] Current Operating System: Linux bilkis 4.9.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) i686
[   155.427] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-686-pae root=UUID=c76b037c-2f29-4fdc-8a2a-5540d9fb09ed ro quiet
[   155.428] Build Date: 07 July 2017  06:13:53AM
[   155.428] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   155.428] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   155.428]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   155.428] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   155.429] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Sep  3 19:56:07 2017
[   155.481] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   155.481] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   155.481] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   155.547] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   155.547] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   155.547] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   155.555] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   155.555] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "NVidia 9600 GT"
[   155.555] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Device0"
[   155.555] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   155.555] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   155.555] (**) Option "Xinerama" "0"
[   155.555] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   155.555] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   155.555] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   155.555] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   155.594] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   155.594]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   155.633] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   155.633] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   155.633] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   155.633] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   155.633] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   155.633] (II) Loader magic: 0x802fa720
[   155.633] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   155.633]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   155.633]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   155.633]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   155.633]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   155.634] (++) using VT number 1

[   155.638] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   155.638] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   155.638] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[   155.639] (--) PCI:*(0:4:0:0) 10de:0622:0000:0000 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xfa000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   155.639] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   155.672] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[   157.502] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   157.502]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   157.502]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   157.502] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.102  Mon Jan 16 12:20:46 PST 2017
[   157.502] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   157.531] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   157.627] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   157.627]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   157.627]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   157.641] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  340.102  Mon Jan 16 11:59:14 PST 2017
[   157.641] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   157.653] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   157.653] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   157.653] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   157.663] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   157.663]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   157.663]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   157.663] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[   157.663] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   157.663] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   157.663] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   157.671] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   157.671]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   157.671]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   157.671] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   157.671] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   157.671] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   157.684] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   157.684] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   157.684] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   157.684] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   157.691] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "yes"
[   157.691] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "Off"
[   157.691] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ModeValidation" "NoEdidModes"
[   157.692] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA SLI disabled.
[   157.692] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseEDID" "False"
[   157.692] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   157.692] (**) NVIDIA(0): Ignoring EDIDs
[   158.899] (II) NVIDIA(0): Not probing EDID on CRT-1.
[   158.899] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20150116)
[   158.903] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 9600 GT (G94) at PCI:4:0:0 (GPU-0)
[   158.903] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[   158.903] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 62.94.0d.00.00
[   158.903] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 9600 GT at PCI:4:0:0
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1 (boot, connected)
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0):     TV-0
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): TV-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   158.905] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   158.905] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   158.905] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-1 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[   158.905] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[   158.905] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Mode Validation Overrides for CRT-1:
[   158.905] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     NoEdidModes
[   158.917] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[   158.917] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-1:1280x1024R"
[   158.917] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1280 x 1024
[   158.940] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-1's EDID; cannot compute DPI
[   158.940] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-1's EDID.
[   158.940] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[   158.940] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   158.941] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[   158.946] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-1:1280x1024R"
[   159.050] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   159.050] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[   159.050] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   159.052] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   159.052] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreEDID" is not used
[   159.052] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   159.052] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   159.052] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   159.052] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   159.052] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   159.053] (--) RandR disabled
[   159.060] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   159.061] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   159.061] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.(II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[   159.386] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   159.386] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   159.387] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   159.424] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   159.424]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.23.0
[   159.424]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   159.424]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   159.424] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   159.425] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 37 paused 0
[   159.425] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   159.425] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   159.425] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   159.426] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.426] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[   159.426] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7/event4"
[   159.426] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   159.426] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   159.426] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[   159.426] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[   159.426] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:caps_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
[   159.463] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.463] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[   159.464] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   159.464] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   159.464] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   159.464] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 40 paused 0
[   159.464] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   159.464] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   159.464] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   159.465] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.465] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[   159.465] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input6/event3"
[   159.465] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   159.465] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   159.465] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[   159.465] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[   159.465] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:caps_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
[   159.465] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.465] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[   159.466] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event7)
[   159.466] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   159.466] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   159.466] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[   159.466] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   159.466] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   159.467] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Rear Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[   159.467] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   159.467] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   159.467] (II) config/udev: Adding input device   USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[   159.467] (**)   USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   159.467] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '  USB Keyboard'
[   159.468] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 41 paused 0
[   159.468] (**)   USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[   159.468] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   159.468] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   159.468] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.468] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[   159.468] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:05AF:0802.0001/input/input3/event0"
[   159.468] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "  USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   159.468] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   159.468] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[   159.468] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[   159.468] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:caps_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
[   159.469] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.469] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[   159.470] (II) config/udev: Adding input device   USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[   159.470] (**)   USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   159.470] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '  USB Keyboard'
[   159.470] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 42 paused 0
[   159.470] (**)   USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[   159.470] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   159.470] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   159.471] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.471] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[   159.471] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:05AF:0802.0002/input/input4/event1"
[   159.471] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "  USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   159.471] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   159.471] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[   159.471] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[   159.471] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:caps_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
[   159.472] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   159.472] (II) input device '  USB Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[   159.472] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event2)
[   159.472] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   159.472] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse'
[   159.532] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 43 paused 0
[   159.532] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[   159.532] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   159.532] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   159.532] (II) input device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   159.532] (II) Device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse' set to 400 DPI
[   159.532] (II) input device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[   159.532] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C00E.0003/input/input5/event2"
[   159.532] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[   159.532] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   159.532] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   159.532] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   159.533] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   159.533] (II) input device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   159.533] (II) Device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse' set to 400 DPI
[   159.533] (II) input device 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[   159.534] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   159.534] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   159.534] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   159.534] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[   159.534] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   159.534] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   165.875] (WW) NVIDIA(0): WAIT (2, 4, 0x8000, 0xdfff2fff, 0x000022f4)
```

And when run as a root:
https://pastebin.com/X36Esu5w

I believe that problem is driver-related, because I also have Debian 8 with no nvidia-legacy drivers on another disk and it runs without a problem.

Tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: You may try a newer nvidia driver. If you have an older nvidia card, then an older one (nvidia likes to forget their older cards). [Here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is the Ubuntu PPA for the proprietary nvidia drivers, and [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) is the Debian doc.

Answer (score 1):

One of the bug reports say it works with kernel 4.7. I could not try it - not in the repository anymore.

Here nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver bug reports: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver;dist=stable

My fail attempts with 9600 GT (my PCI ID is 622):

1. kernel 4.9

1.1. and nvidia-driver - module does not load

1.2. and nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver - computer hangs up before X server

1.3. and nvidia-legacy-30xx-driver - computer hangs up before X server

2. kernel 4.11 (backports) and nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver - fail (probably computer hangs up, I do not remember)
3. kernel 3.16 (oldstable) and nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver - module does not load

Another similar question, no answer: [Failed to load module 'nvidia' after upgrading to Stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381049/failed-to-load-module-nvidia-after-upgrading-to-stretch)

Comment: OK, what about free drivers, like nouveau, etc? Do you have any experience using them, do they have fine performance?

Comment: Nouveau leads to random crashes right when you work.

Answer (score -1):

If your running an APU you may need to enable SLI.

An APU is a processor that includes both the CPU and GPU on a single chip. The name “APU” was coined by AMD, which released the first APU in January, 2011.

For many years, CPUs handled all non-graphics calculations, while GPUs were only used for graphics operations. - Nov 14, 2013

APU (Accelerated Processing Unit) Definition - TechTerms

By itself, a single 9600 GT scored 10036 points in 3DMark06, but when combined in SLI the two cards managed an impressive 13080 points - over 900 points above the score of a GeForce 8800 Ultra (12142) on the same system. ...Jan 29, 2008

```
NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT SLI Benchmarked | TechPowerUp

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option "IgnoreEDID" "true"
   # Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
   Option "UseEDID" "False"
   Option "SLI" "Off"
   SubSection     "Display"
          Depth       24
          Modes    "1280x1024_75.00"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Please see that the information you are providing are correct and the question being addressed. These principles are even more important when this is about a late answer such as yours.